# Separating mixture of two different coordinate systems in PostGIS table

Tags: python, postgis, postgresql, geopandas

One PostGIS table includes features (point, lines, polygons) with two different coordinate systems: EPSG:27700 (BGN) and EPSG:4325 (WGS84).

Spatial extent of the table in WGS84:

52.6967,-3.1401
50.8598,0.4692

I have tried to find WGS84 geometries that includes negative coordinate values but some features are only positive coordinates.

Is there any solution in Python or PostGIS to detect the features in one coordinate system so I can project them into another.

Comment: I didnt think it was posisble to have a geometry column with different geometry types and coordinate systems in it. What is the data type of the column?

Comment: Coordinates were not originally defined as two different CRSs. Some geometries were in EPSG:4326 but defined in EPSG:27700 and was pushed to the database.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`st_srid`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SRID.html):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM ..
WHERE st_srid(geometry) = 4326;
```